# Java regular expression to check time format

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string which i need to validate for format -1D23H13M40S. (case insensitive)

What can be the regular expression??

I have tried

```
myString.matches("[^0-9MHDS]*")
```

Comment: i tried - myString.matches("[^0-9MHDS]*")

Comment: Is it a negative sign before the pattern, or just something you added to separate the pattern from the rest of the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
\d+D(\d|[01]\d|2[0-4])H(\d|[0-5]\d|60)M(\d|[0-5]\d|60)S
```

Or this one to exclude time limits such as `24H`, `60M` and `60S`:

```
\d+D(\d|[01]\d|2[0-3])H(\d|[0-5]\d)M(\d|[0-5]\d)S
```

Comment: You're right, I made an update.

Comment: well hours should not exceed 24, minutes and second 60 :)

Comment: @nhahtdh, OK, I updated it again.

Comment: @Gabro Added an alternative pattern.

Comment: This is now fine. But it doesn't handle case-insensitivity. Add a `(?i)` at the beginning of the pattern to enable it.